# Is there a specific word for "developing a liking towards someone after someone else says they are nice"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose there are three children A, B and C.
A is friends with B.
B is friends with C.

A however is indifferent towards C. But when B says to A that C is a nice person, A begins to feel so too.

Is there a name for this phenomenon? (say, liking by conduction, convection or radiation, ... or something along the lines of that.)

Comment: A is definitely being ***impressionable***, though that describes the person, not the phenomenon.

Comment: Or [suggestible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggestible), in which case you could reasonably refer to the phenomenon itself as [suggestibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suggestibility) *- the quality of being inclined to accept and act on the suggestions of others **where false but plausible information is given*** (cf [gullible](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gullible) *- easily deceived or cheated*). Idiomatically, perhaps ***easily-led***.

Comment: (You could have ***sheep-like*** for the adjective, but not ***sheepish*** - and certainly not ***sheepishness*** for the noun! :)

Comment: You're describing an everyday *referral*. It's not necessarily childish. Wouldn't you trust a friend to introduce you to your betrothed over a random meeting?

Comment: I think there's no word like that… and did you mean *… after people after someone…*?

Comment: Does B say it only once and A begins to feel so or does B make statements to that effect multiple times and A begins to feel so? If the latter, "conditioning" would be what I'd use.

Comment: @Robert - it takes multiple attempts and could you explain how can we call it conditioning?

Comment: well, I could be totally wrong, but if B, when speaking of C, outlines the case over time that C is a good person or what have you, then A is being conditioned to have an agreeable response over time towards C ("I've heard so many good things about you" kind of interaction).

Comment: if it were a general case where A knows C, and then over time goes from indifferent to liking C, that may be warming, but with B's direct involvement, it would not be simply that (A's feelings as they relate to C are being affected by an outside entity)

Comment: Perhaps related to [*memetics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memetics).

Comment: a type of conditioning:  experimental extinction, extinction - a conditioning process in which the reinforcer [when B says to A that C is a nice person] ends and a conditioned response [ A begins to feel so too] becomes independent of the conditioned stimulus.

Comment: Well, copycatting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copycat

Comment: to reconsider the person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A begins to like C **by extension**.

B's good opinion of C is **contagious**.

A slight variant of your situation:  A and B are friends, and B is a fan of C.  Let's say B talks up C in conversations with A.  Then we can say that B **turns A onto C.**

And now I'll invent something for this purpose.  If A and B are friends, and B and C are friends, then A and C are likely to become friends **by the transitive law of friendship.**

*If OP is still interested in this and is particularly interested in one or another of my suggestions, or is confused about anything, I'd be happy to provide documentation.*

Answer (score 0):

Child A is more "apt" to liking Child B.

[Apt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apt)

1. having a tendency : likely plants apt to suffer from drought
2. ordinarily disposed : inclined apt to accept what is plausible as true

[Similiarity/Attraction Theory](https://www.encyclopedia.com/social-sciences/applied-and-social-sciences-magazines/similarityattraction-theory) describes the phenomenon.

> sharing similar attitudes provides corroboration that a person is not alone in his or her belief; they might even be correct to hold the attitude in question. Other possible reasons suggested for why people prefer others who are similar to themselves are that (1) knowledge of similar attitudes may help people to predict others’ future behaviors, providing a predictive “window” into the other’s behavioral predilections, and **(2) people may be more likely to assume that others who hold similar attitudes to themselves have a greater chance of being attracted to them, a “likeness begets liking” explanation.**

Answer (score -2):

predisposition is the word I would use
A was predisposed to C via B's good opinion

Comment: This has the makings of a good answer but it needs a reference to a source and a citation of usage in order to be worthy of an up-vote, in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think predisposition works here; A is indifferent towards C 'originally'.

Comment: A good expert answer includes explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the asker, but to future visitors to the page. Please consider expanding your answer.